# Lambda function as callable in .iloc[]

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to use `Lambda` as a callable into `.iloc[]`

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['sdfg',23,'MrkA',34,0,56],'B':['jfgh',23,45,'Mrk1',0,56],\
                   'C':['cvb',7,65,65,47,3],'D':['rrb',7,76,3,0,7],\
                   'E':['dfg',7,'MrkA',5,12,1],'F':['dfg',7,2,'Mrk2',0,4],'G':['dfg',7,1,5,8,9],\
                   'H':['dfg',7,'MrkA',5,0,8],'I':['dfg',7,56,'Mrk3',7,23]})
    
   
    
l1=[lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2]
l2=[lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2, lambda c:c+4,lambda c:c+5]
l3=[lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2, lambda c:c+4,lambda c:c+5, lambda c:c+7,lambda c:c+8]
    
    
#number of instances of MrkA=1 then pass in l1
if df.count('MrkA')==1:
    l=l1
    print(l1)
#number of instances of MrkA=2 then pass in l2
elif df.count('MrkA')==2:
    l=l2
    print(l2)
#number of instances of MrkA=3 then pass in l3
else: 
    l=l3
    print(l3)

for c in range(df.shape[1]):
    for r in range(df.shape[0]):
        if df.iloc[r, c] == "MrkA" and df.iloc[r + 1, c + 1] == "Mrk1":
            df1=df.iloc[r+1:,[l]]
            break
```

Output: `df`

```
      A     B    C    D     E     F    G     H     I
0  sdfg  jfgh  cvb  rrb   dfg   dfg  dfg   dfg   dfg
1    23    23    7    7     7     7    7     7     7
2  MrkA    45   65   76  MrkA     2    1  MrkA    56
3    34  Mrk1   65    3     5  Mrk2    5     5  Mrk3
4     0     0   47    0    12     0    8     0     7
5    56    56    3    7     1     4    9     8    23
```

Output `df1`

```
.iloc requires numeric indexers, got [[<function <lambda> at 0x0000021EBD67AA60>
  <function <lambda> at 0x0000021EBD67A8B0>
  <function <lambda> at 0x0000021EBD67A820>]]
```

Desired Output: for 3 instances of `MrkA`

```
    A     B   C   E     F  H     I
3  34  Mrk1  65   5  Mrk2  5  Mrk3
4   0     0  47  12     0  0     7
5  56    56   3   1     4  8    23
```

Any suggestions? I want to apply logic with something like Lambda because the number of columns I want will depend on other parameters in my real `df`(excel sheet)

Comment: @user9106985--In your example you select columns c, c+1, c+2.  If this is not fixed, what is the basis (logic) for what columns are selected?   Are you asking how to specify a function of these three columns?

Comment: @DarryIG: I have edited my original post to illustrate my desired logic. It is not complete as I need to also figure out how to count the number of instances of `MrkA`. I think you will get the general idea of what I am trying to do

Comment: @user9106985--1) df.count('MrkA') provides an error?  Are you trying to finding the number of times MrkA occurs in the entire DataFrame df?  2) In this case there are 3 occurrences so why is the desired result the first case (i.e. for count = 1) rather than the third case?

Comment: Your code sample contains errors. The problem is with *df.count('MrkA')*.
Note that *count* function counts non-NA cells in the specified axis (*0* - in each column, *1* - in each row).
What do you attempt to count here?
Instances of *'MrkA'* in each row / column / whole DataFrame?

Comment: @DarrylG Yes there is an error  with .count which I am trying to correct. My real dataframe will be from a spreadsheet to which I will not know the number of occurrences of a particular string. That is why I need logic. My `df` here is only for demonstration purposes. Desired result is just for demonstration

Comment: @user9106985--posted an answer.  Does this illustrate your desired logic?

Comment: @Valdi_Bo `MrkA` will occur on one row in my whole dataframe (coming from spreadsheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your code sample contains an error df.count('MrkA').  count expects an axis
2. Use lambda c: [c, c+...] to specify desired columns.

Following code based upon finding count of MrKA in the entire DataFrame.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['sdfg',23,'MrkA',34,0,56],'B':['jfgh',23,45,'Mrk1',0,56],\
                   'C':['cvb',7,65,65,47,3],'D':['rrb',7,76,3,0,7],\
                   'E':['dfg',7,'MrkA',5,12,1],'F':['dfg',7,2,'Mrk2',0,4],'G':['dfg',7,1,5,8,9],\
                   'H':['dfg',7,'MrkA',5,0,8],'I':['dfg',7,56,'Mrk3',7,23]})

l1=lambda c: [c, c+1, c+2] # [lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2]
l2=lambda c: [c, c+1, c+2, c+4, c+5] #[lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2, lambda c:c+4,lambda c:c+5]
l3=lambda c: [c, c+1, c+2,c+4, c+5, c+7, c+8] #[lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2, lambda c:c+4,lambda c:c+5, lambda c:c+7,lambda c:c+8]
    
#number of instances of MrkA=1 then pass in l1
if df[df=='MrkA'].size==1:
    l=l1
    print('Count == 1', l1)
#number of instances of MrkA=2 then pass in l2
elif df[df=='MrkA'].size==2:
    l=l2
    print('Count = 2', l2)
#number of instances of MrkA=3 then pass in l3
else: 
    l=l3
    print('Else Clause', l3)

for c in range(df.shape[1]):
    for r in range(df.shape[0]):
        if df.iloc[r, c] == "MrkA" and df.iloc[r + 1, c + 1] == "Mrk1":
            df1=df.iloc[r+1:, l(c)]
            break
print()
print(df)
print()
print(df1)
```

**Alternate Solution** using your original lambdas

```
l1 = [lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2]
l2 = [lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2, lambda c:c+4,lambda c:c+5]
l3=[lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2, lambda c:c+4,lambda c:c+5, lambda c:c+7,lambda c:c+8]
    
#number of instances of MrkA=1 then pass in l1
if df[df=='MrkA'].size==1:
    l=l1
    print('Count == 1', l1)
#number of instances of MrkA=2 then pass in l2
elif df[df=='MrkA'].size==2:
    l=l2
    print('Count = 2', l2)
#number of instances of MrkA=3 then pass in l3
else: 
    l=l3
    print('Else Clause', l3)

for c in range(df.shape[1]):
    for r in range(df.shape[0]):
        if df.iloc[r, c] == "MrkA" and df.iloc[r + 1, c + 1] == "Mrk1":
            # l is an array of functions
            # use list comprehension to obtain
            # array of values
            df1=df.iloc[r+1:, [f(c) for f in l]]
            break
```

**Output**  -- Both Methods

```
Else Clause <function <lambda> at 0x7f2fde12f550>

      A     B    C    D     E     F    G     H     I
0  sdfg  jfgh  cvb  rrb   dfg   dfg  dfg   dfg   dfg
1    23    23    7    7     7     7    7     7     7
2  MrkA    45   65   76  MrkA     2    1  MrkA    56
3    34  Mrk1   65    3     5  Mrk2    5     5  Mrk3
4     0     0   47    0    12     0    8     0     7
5    56    56    3    7     1     4    9     8    23

    A     B   C   E     F  H     I
3  34  Mrk1  65   5  Mrk2  5  Mrk3
4   0     0  47  12     0  0     7
5  56    56   3   1     4  8    23
```

Comment: I need to apply logic because it is "not known a priori" the number of columns, ie my real `df` will be read in from an excel sheet.

Comment: @DarryIG Thanks! Almost correct. Your version of `l3` does not reproduce the desired columns. I have edited my original post to show desired df1 for 3 instances of `MrkA` I will see can I adjust it

Comment: @user9106985--what are the desired columns for 3 instances?  Your post has `l3=[lambda c:c, lambda c:c+1,lambda c:c+2, lambda c:c+4,lambda c:c+5, lambda c:c+7,lambda c:c+8]`.  I noticed this does not include c+6 but assumed that was an error.  Do you want the columns without c+6?

Comment: @DarryIG. I want columns ` A     B   C   E     F  H     I` ,  ie,  i do not want columns `c+3, c+6`

Comment: @user9106985--updated answer to more correspond to columns in your lambda expression.

Comment: @DarryIG Great thanks, that works. I have never seen the form of the expression for lambda...can you briefly? Also I am curious how `l(c)` works? If I enter it by itself the kernel keeps running...

Comment: @user9106985--`l1=lambda c: [c, c+1, c+2]` is equivalent to defining an function i.e. `def l1: return [c, c+1, c+2]`.  In the latter case hopefully l1(c) then makes sense.  However, [PEP 8--the Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), discourages using lambda functions in this way and prefers the latter function definition approach.